# Why did we pass through passport control after a Budapest-Milan flight?

Tags: schengen, italy, hungary

I was really puzzled when landing at Milan Malpensa (on a Wizz Air flight from Budapest) we needed to go through a passport control. How come? I thought if you don't leave Schengen you don't need a passport control.

Comment: Similar has happened to me in Italy. Our plane was guided to extra-Schengen arrivals and everyone but one passenger was waved through passport control (literally waved through, no need for documents), the poor fellow who had to get his passport seems to clearly have been singled out before.

Comment: Did they stamp your passport? I presume they were looking for refugees trying to exploit the Schengen rules.

Comment: Since I passed through with a Schengen passport, no stamps. I do not know what went in the "all passports" lane.

Comment: It has happened to me occasionally on intra-Schengen flights as well, independent of the current refugee situation. I wonder if some authorities pre-scan passenger manifests for interesting subjects and then channel all passengers through passport control if they find someone they might want to talk to on an inbound and otherwise immigration excempt flight?

Comment: @JonathanReez During internal border checks, passports are not stamped

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Due to the situation in Europe, many sovereign states have re-instituted immigration checks.  Checks could possibly be performed randomly or continuously is some circumstances.

If you search on "suspend Schengen" or "Europe border controls", you will see numbers reports of this over the past months, particularly with respect to France, Italy, Austria and Denmark.